# Testing for expected 404 with Django test client leads to unhandled exception

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, django-unittest

I'm using the Django test client, `django.test.client.Client`, to test some views in a Django app. In particular, I'm testing a case where the view calls a `get_object_or_404` method and the object isn't there, so a 404 should be returned.

My test code looks like this:

```
class ViewTests(TestCase):
    fixtures=['test.json']

    def test_thing_not_there_get(self):
        url = '/foo/30afda98-b9d7-4e26-a59a-76ac1b6a001f/'
        c = django.test.client.Client()
        response = c.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

However, what I'm getting instead is an unhandled exception error in the view code:

```
python projects/unittests/manage.py test 
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
......ERROR:root:Unhandled Exception on request for http://testserver/foo/30afda98-b9d7-4e26-a59a-76ac1b6a001f/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lorin/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorin/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 39, in wrapped_view
    resp = view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorin/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 52, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorin/django-myvenv/apps/myvenv_desktop/views.py", line 85, in foo_view
    instance = get_object_or_404(Foo, uuid=foo_uuid)
  File "/Users/lorin/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 115, in get_object_or_404
    raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
Http404: No Foo matches the given query.
```

According to the [Django 1.3 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/)

> The only exceptions that are not visible to the test client are
>   Http404, PermissionDenied and SystemExit. Django catches these
>   exceptions internally and converts them into the appropriate HTTP
>   response codes. In these cases, you can check response.status_code in
>   your test.

Why isn't Django catching the Http404 exception in this case?

Note that (in conformance with the docs), the exception is *not* being thrown across into the test client. If I try to catch the exception on the client side:

```
with self.assertRaises(django.http.Http404):
    response = c.get(url)
```

I get the same error, as well as an additional error:

```
AssertionError: Http404 not raised
```

Comment: But, according to your answer, django must return a 404 response code, it's a django error, not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is from a while ago, but I solved this so I figured it's worth sharing. What you need to do is customize the error handler in your code. For example, I have:

in urls.py:

```
from myapp.views import error_handler
handler404 = error_handler.error404
```

and the function error404:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
def error404(request):
    t = loader.get_template('404.html')
    html = t.render(Context())

    return HttpResponseNotFound(html)
```

If you send a `HttpResponseNotFound` object, it will interpret as a 404 status code.

**EDIT**

In newer versions of django its ok just to put a `404.html` in the templates directory. The above controller is only necessary if you need more logic than just showing the error page.

Answer (score 2):

Upon further inspection, it looks like the test is passing as written: the error message doesn't actually correspond to a test failure.